# howto process non-numeric text file and convert into struct most efficiently?

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of `.txt` files that have the following format:

```
|file | time | color     | tags       |
|1    | 1:10 | red       | ok, correct|
|2    | 2:20 | blue      | bad        |
|3    | 1:20 | yellow    | sometag    |
```

The first row specifies the column names.
The subsequent rows are 'database' entries.

I want to read in this file, and put all the information into a Matlab structure. I'm wondering what the most efficient way of doing this is.

- `textread` with `'delimiter', '\n'` and process each line individually?
- `textread` with `'delimiter', '|'` and having to determine which entries belong together?
- `fread` line by line?

I love the convenience of `textread` with `'delimiter', '\n'` but then it's quite a pain to get out the individual entries for each column (with a `for` loop). Alternatively I can split each row up using `regexp`:

```
regexp(file{1}, '\|', 'split')
```

But this will only split up each row, and won't take care of the whitespaces (for which I would need another `regexp` call to in order to get rid of).

So what's the most straight forward (and maybe even most efficient) way of doing this?

**EDIT1** I want to build a struct like `db = struct('file', [], 'time', [], 'color', [], 'tags')` which is easy to create once I've read-in the first line.

Comment: there is also [textscan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html). I'm not sure if it applies here (I think the spaces might give problems)... BTW: you want an array of structs, or a struct with arrays?

Comment: How should the time be saved? as a string? `time.minutes` &  `time.seconds`? converted to seconds?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf time will stay a string. actually, most field will stay as strings, only `file` is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html):

```
fid = fopen('asdf.txt');
header = textscan(fid, '%s', 5, 'delimiter', '|');
data=textscan(fid, '|%d %s %s %s','delimiter','|');
fclose(fid);
```

which gives:

```
data =
    [3x1 double]    {3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}
```

From here it's easy to go to the struct you wanted. The strings also have some extra spaces, which need trimming:

```
data{2} = strtrim(data{2});
```